# What's the difference between the code and code-block directives in ReST?

Tags: python-sphinx, restructuredtext

In every renderer I've tried, `code` and `code-block` seem to have the exact same result: a block of code.  Both generate the exact same html -- including classes and tag kind (using I think it was docutils?):

```html
<pre class="code [language] literal-block">
```

So, what's the difference?  Why do we have both?  Are there any renderers that render them differently?  Is there a semantic difference?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

`code` is a reStructuredText directive.
`code-block` is a Sphinx directive.

The `code-block` has a different set of options to the `code`directive.
E.g. `:emphasize-lines:`

As you are using Sphinx I would recommend using the `code-block` directive.

When using `code-block` I always get the correct highlighting. When using `code` I sometimes get colors and sometimes just literal code blocks. I have yet to figure out what combinations of setting in conf.py that predictably generates colored output.

The `code` directive does have the advantage that the document can be used both in a Sphinx document tree and at the same time as a stand-alone reStructuredText document.